# How to connect NIDEC RH7-1460000CN

Tags: dc-motor

I have a Nidec 50M0600010 (HP p/n RH7-1460000CN) DC motor and I'd be happy using it in my leisure time project. I am a bit confused seeing 5 wires: GND; /VACC; /VDEC/; MFG and +25.5V. Two of them I recognize, but how could I have motor running with controlled speed?

Comment: don't post a correction in a comment  ... please edit your question and make the necessary changes there ... and delete  the comment